# Glut Mouse Coordinates

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to obtain the Cartesian coordinates of a point for that I am using a simple function the devolves a window coordinates, something like (100,200). I want to convert this to Cartesian coordinates, the problems is that the window size is variable so I really don't know how to implement this.

Edit:

Op:

I tried to use the guUnPorject by doing something like this

```
GLdouble modelMatrix[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,modelMatrix);
GLdouble projMatrix[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,projMatrix);


double position[3];
 gluUnProject(
  x,
   y,
  1,
 modelMatrix,
 projMatrix,
 viewport,
 &position[0], //-&gt; pointer to your own position (optional)
 &position[1], // id
 &position[2] // 
 );

 cout<<position[0];
```

However the position I got seems completely random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse coordinates are already in cartesian coordinates, namely the coordinates of window space. I think what you're looking for is a transformation into the world space of your OpenGL scene. The 2D mouse coordinates in the window lack some information thougn: The depth.

So what you can otain is actually a ray from the "camera" into the scene. For this you need to perform the back projection from screen space to world space. For this you take the projection matrix, P and the view matrix V (what's generated by gluLookAt or similar), form the product P*V and invert it i.e. (P*V)^-1 = V^-1 * P^-1. Take notice that inversion is not transposition. Inverting a matrix is done by Gauss-Jordan elimination, preferrably with some pivoting. Any mathtextbook on linear algebra explains it.

Then you need two vectors to form a ray. For this you take two screen space positions with the same XY coordinates but differing depth (say, 0 and 1) and do the backprojection:

```
(P*V)^-1 * (x, y, {0, 1})
```

The difference of the resulting vectors gives you a ray direction.

The whole backprojection process has been wrapped up into gluUnProject. However I recommend not using it in its GLU form, but either look at the source code to learn from it, or use a modern day substitute like it's offered by GLM.

Comment: @user697110: When do you perform the steps, and which projection and modelview matrix do you obtain (i.e. at which point of your program to you fetch them from OpenGL)?

Comment: @user697110: Well at that time you read some projection and modelview, but probably not the one that were present after the view transformation. It will be the last of them on the matrix stack, certainly not what you want. Post your full code (on pastebin.com) and I'll modify it to work.

Comment: Well thanks for your help, but I just discovered that after all in this work we don't require to use zoom, rotation or variable windows, so it just makes the work much simpler. Thanks for your help anyway