# How to convert from GLUT coordinates to window coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Glut Mouse Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371682/glut-mouse-coordinates)

Let's say that I have a window of 600x600.
When I receive mouse events I don't know what's the real position of the mouse, in OpenGL I use this to draw points:

```
(-0.5,0.5) | (0.5,0.5)
           |
 --------(0,0)-------
           |
           |
(-0.5,-0.5) | (0.5,-0.5)
```

But when I receive GLUT mouse events depending on the size of the window I get different coordinates.I want a relative (to the window) coordinate system.How do I get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure glut gives you the mouse coordinates in window space (i.e. if the window is 800x600 and the mouse position is in the middle, it will give you x: 400, y: 300), so if you want to bring that to the opengl space you posted above, you would do the following:

```
float x = (400 / 800) - 0.5f; //0.0
float y = (300 / 600) - 0.5f; //0.0
```

so a generic version would look something like this:

```
float mouseX = (theGlutMouseXCoordinate / theGlutWindowWidth) - 0.5f;
float mouseY = (theGlutMouseYCoordinate / theGlutWindowHeight) - 0.5f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misreading your question, or oversimplifying the answer, but aren't you just looking for something like:

```
float x = mouse.x / screen.width;  //x now in [0,1]
float y = mouse.y / screen.height; //y now in [0,1]
x-=0.5f;
y-=0.5f;
```

Or reversed:

```
float wx = (x + 0.5f) * screen.width;
float wy = (Y + 0.5f) * screen.height;
```